# Is there a way to write a program in JS and compile it as *.exe file?

Tags: javascript, exe

I want to create a simple program running on Windows that fetches some information from the Internet and displays it to a user in a dialogue window or something like this. I have some knowledge of JS. Is it even possible to do this without having to learn another programming language? If not, what technology I should look into? Visual Basic, C++ or something else?

Comment: You can have a look to http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Perhaps you could just use JScript.

Comment: @Areca, thank you good sir/lady! It's exactly what I need!